# error with default value in Databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

As described in [Databinding document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#studio_support) we can use `default` to check value in preview pane.

It is working perfectly if i have simple String like below :

```
android:text="@{place, default=Columbia}"
```

But i have combination of state and country and if i am using ,(comma) then it is creating problem.

```
android:text="@{place, default=Gujarat, IN}"
```

It is showing error `, unexpected`, How to resolve it?

[image]

I know still we can use `tools:text` to check output in preview pane, but how to overcome this issue in `Databinding` with `default`?

Answer (score 7):

Changing the ticks will work, but it'll show the ticks:

```
android:text='@{place, default="Gujarat, IN"}'
```

What you can do, is to create a string resource:

```
<string name="placeholder">Placeholder, text</string>
```

And use it as default value:

```
android:text='@{viewModel.placeHolder, default=@string/placeholder}'
```

Comment: Oops, I did not see that. I'll investigate further :)

Comment: I found a solution :)

Comment: Great :) , does it mean we can not write this kind of string directly in our layout file?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think so. But maybe they will add this feature somehow :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the entire value.
For example:

```
android:text='@{place, default="Gujarat, IN"}'
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use *double quotes* with *back quotes* or *single quotes* with *double quote*s. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#string_literals) Android developer document reference.

1st way

```
android:text="@{place, default=`Gujarat, IN`}"
```

2nd way

```
android:text='@{place, default="Gujarat, IN"}'
```